# How can I view all code changes by an author?

Tags: git, filter, version-control

For example, I have a project like this

```
[ID]--[Date]-------[Commit message]-------[Author]

[5]--[Today]-------[Update Feature A]-----[Michael]

[4]--[Yesterday]---[Add Feature Y]--------[Tom]

[3]--[1 day ago]---[Add Feature X]--------[Dick]

[2]--[2 days ago]--[Add feature A]--------[Michael]

[1]--[3 days ago]--[First commit]---------[Michael]
```

I am using Git Extensions, and I can't find a way to view diff by author Michael only.

For example, I just want to see changed code of feature A, when I click commit 1 and 2, I can see the diff between these commit. But when I filter author [Michael], and click 1 and 5, I expect to see all the diff by author [Michael] only - but there are diff by [Tom] and [Dick] also.

Is there any way I can view all code changes by an author? I don't care which tool I use (like SourceTree, Git Extensions,...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view all commits by a particular author with `git log --author=<pattern>` where the pattern is a regular expression.

But you seem to want to take the diff between commits of changes done only by a certain author, ignoring the commits between. This goes against Git's nature. A Git commit is, conceptually, not a diff. Rather each commit is a complete snapshot of the state of all the files at the time of the commit. You can't take a diff between 1 and 5 while ignoring 2, 3, and 4 because 5 is the culmination of 1, 2, 3, and 4.

You could [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) 1 and 5 into a temporary branch (and deal with all the conflicts), but I believe you're trying to solve the wrong problem. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you really want is to see all the changes on "feature A". In this case they happen to be done by a single author, but that won't always be the case.

Instead, what you want is to organize your features into individual branches, aptly named "feature branches" or "topic branches". One branch for each feature. The branch is not merged until the feature is ***done*** and then it is deleted. This is the basic way you allow multiple people to work on multiple features without prematurely sharing unfinished work and getting in each other's way.

Then when you want to look at just changes to feature A you can look at the branch for feature A, no matter who has worked on that feature.

You can read more about [Branching Workflows in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows).

Comment: Oh, I got it. So I think I can write a tool to do my case. Like this:

1. Get all the latest files that Michael has changed.

2. Diff between Michael's file and the initial (original) commit files.

3. Tada - I got what I want.

Now all I have to do is find these git command. Thank you :D

Comment: @123iamking I strongly suggest you consider this a one-off problem and use feature branches going forward. They eliminate many problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :D and  XY Problem knowledge is a great one - thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 6):

Old question but for the sake of those who search for it - here is how it can be done.

1. Get all commits by the requested user ( `git log -author | grep` )
2. Extract the commit hash out of the output ( `awk -F` )
3. Run git show on those hashes ( `git show`)

End here is the complete command :

```
git show `git log --author=bob | grep ^commit | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: If you want to see just the list of commits and changes you can use `git log -p --author=bob`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git log --author="author_name"
```